# How to read values from SimpleXmlElement object in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, xml, simplexml

I found many answers regarding my question but still I'm unable to achieve my goal.
I've a API endpoint which returns me [this](http://ecarrefour.com/test/api/saveProducts.php):

I want to read all the data returned by the API. Here is my code:

```
<?php
  $xml=json_decode(json_encode(file_get_contents('http://ecarrefour.com/test/api/saveProducts.php')),true);
  $val= $xml->availability;
  echo $val; 
?>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\work\index.php on line 4
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `json_decode(..., true)` returns an array. If everything else is correct, try with `json_decode(..., false)`. But I don;t know why you use `JSON` functions when your question is about `SimpleXmlElement object in PHP`.

Comment: URL http://ecarrefour.com/test/api/saveProducts.php is not returning valid XML. It is just returning some debug array.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems with your code that I can notice:

First issue is the true parameter passed to json_decode, which will decode the JSON to array and NOT object. json_decode decodes by default to object, but if you pass true as the second parameter you get an array.

That's why you get the error message, as in your situation $xml is an array.

The other issue I'm noticing is the output of the API script. That output looks like print_r output, which is not correct.

Here's what you need to do:

1. In the API script, don't print_r($simpleXmlObject). You can use the asXML method on your simpleXml object to get the XML which you can then output.
2. In your client script, first run file_get_contents to get the needed XML.
3. You can then create the simpleXML object on the client side from that XML, using something like:

`$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_string);`

4. Now you can do the json_decode to json_encode trick you're doing above on $xml, to convert it from SimpleXML to array or object.

That should do the trick.

Comment: @SorinNuncaI  I cannot modify the API as its not at my end, can you please provide a solution using the same thing?

Comment: @mubsher You might have some luck with the print_r_reverse function from here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#121259

I have not tried it, but you should be able to run that function on the file_get_contents result to turn it back into a SimpleXML object directly.  Worth giving it a try.